# Base_url() is adding unnecessary segments into my url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, authentication, base-url

My base_url() is adding more bits into the url than it should be. What is wrong with my setup? I have the helper set up in config.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

My base_url() is set to: index.php/

So the problem is that when I activate this form:

```
<h1>sometimes haikus don't make sense refrigerator</h1>
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>welcome/login_submit" method="post">
    <label>
        email:
        <input id="email" name="email" />
    </label>
    <label>
        password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Log me in!" />
</form>
```

The first time I access it, I'll type in: localhost/CIintranet/ and the the base_url() gets added next so it becomes: localhost/CIintranet/index.php/

I'm trying to program a login logout system though. So if the user login is incorrect, I want it to redirect back to the login page. Here's the code from the controller for that part:

```
public function login_submit() {
        $this->load->model('LoginChecker', 'users');
        //$this->load->view('login_submit');

        $match = $this->users->authenticate_user( $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );
        if( $match )
        {
            $this->load->view('login_submit');
            echo "User exists in database!";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login_form');
            echo "<h1>Email or password is wrong, bretheren!</h1>";
        }
    }
```

But when it reloads the login_form, it adds another part into the url and the url fails. So the progression is like this:

Page loads to this url:

```
localhost/CIintranet/
```

First failed attempt (page still loads properly):

```
localhost/CIintranet/index.php/welcome/login_submit
```

Second failed attempt (page fails to load):

```
localhost/CIintranet/index.php/welcome/index.php/welcome/login_submit
```

I've been doing some research on this for a bit now and I'm noting a lot of people talking about the htaccess file in relation to this problem but nobody seems to mention specifically what fixes it or how to configure the `base_url()` so that it just takes care of this properly. I tried looking at the documentation but perhaps I missed something. I didn't find what I was looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the value of $config['base_url'] in config.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting the `base_url` to `/index.php/`? So it has the forward slash at the front too?

Failing that, please try: `http://localhost/CIintranet/index.php/`

It's usually the simple things!

Comment: Tried the first and it still didn't work. Tried the second and voila. I'm not sure exactly WHY it works but I see what it did. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use ... ?

```
<?php echo form_open('welcome/login_submit') ?>
...
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

activate helper: **form**

Comment: Not that I won't give it a try but is codeigniter forms really the only way to go about solving this problem? I could've sworn that there must have been a way to solve it by just messing with the base_url or something. I honestly don't know though. If this is the best solution then this is what I'll go with.